# Input keeps asking for more

Tags: c++, input, switch-statement

Context: I'm trying to make a small program in C++ that asks the user to create an account and then log in. When creating an account it asks for role, username, and password. To choose a role you have to input an integer 1-3. The problem arises when it asks me for the role. I input a number, click enter and still lets me input another number instead of going to the next part. So I have to input 2 numbers in total but the program still continues. Once I created the account, I try to log in. It also asks for role, username, password. In the login it works perfectly but it does not let me log in. I am 99% sure it has to be because of that problem. It can be anything else though. I am no expert and I am barely starting programming.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

struct User // struct User stores username and password
{
    string username;
    string password;
    string role;
};

vector<User> users; // vector User stores user data

void createAccount() // function to create account
{
    User user;

    cout << "Select your role: " << endl;
    cout << "1. Tier I 2. Tier II 3. Tier III" << endl;

    int roleChoice; // variable for role selection
    cin >> roleChoice; // user selects role by inputing an integer

    switch (roleChoice) // switch enables 3 possible roles
    {
    case 1:
        user.role = "Tier I";
        break;
    case 2:
        user.role = "Tier II";
        break;
    case 3:
        user.role = "Tier III";
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Invalid role selected. Try again." << endl; // invalid input
        return;
    }

    cin >> user.role;
    cout << "Enter a user name: ";
    cin >> user.username;
    cout << "Enter a password: ";
    cin >> user.password;
    users.push_back(user); // push_back user adds a user to the vector User
    cout << "Account created successfully!\n";

}

bool login(string& loggedInUser)
{
    string username, password, role;
    cout << "Select your role:\n";
    cout << "1. Tier I 2. Tier II 3. Tier III" << endl;

    int roleChoice; // variable for role selection
    cin >> roleChoice; // user selects role by inputing an integer

    switch (roleChoice) // switch enables 3 possible roles
    {
    case 1:
        role = "Tier I";
        break;
    case 2:
        role = "Tier II";
        break;
    case 3:
        role = "Tier III";
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Invalid role selected. Try again.\n"; // invalid input
        return false;
    }

    cout << "Enter your username: ";
    cin >> username;
    cout << "Enter your password: ";
    cin >> password;

    for (const User& user : users) // loop searches for information that matches
    { // const in order to avoid any changes

        // verifies that the information inputed is the same
        if (user.role == role && user.username == username && user.password == password)
        {
            loggedInUser = username;
            cout << "Login succesful. Welcome, " << loggedInUser << " (" << role << ")\n ";
            return true; // if information is correct, user logs in
        }
    }

    cout << "Login failed. Invalid role, username, or password.\n";
    return false;
}


int main()
{
    string loggedInUser;
    int choice;
    do // user chooses to create account, login, or exit
    { 
        cout << "1. Create account\n2. Login\n3. Exit\n";
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            createAccount();
            break;
        case 2:
            if (login(loggedInUser))
            {
                cout << "Welcome, " << loggedInUser << "!\n";

                int loggedInChoice;
                do {
                    std::cout << "1. Perform action 1\n2. Perform action 2\n3. Logout\nEnter your choice: ";
                    std::cin >> loggedInChoice;
                    switch (loggedInChoice)
                    {
                    case 1:
                        // Implement action 1.
                        std::cout << "Action 1 performed.\n";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        // Implement action 2.
                        std::cout << "Action 2 performed.\n";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        std::cout << "Logged out. Goodbye!\n";
                        break;
                    default:
                        std::cout << "Invalid choice. Please try again.\n";
                        break;
                    }
                } while (loggedInChoice != 3);
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Goodbye!\n";
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid choice. Try again.\n";
            break;
        }

        
    } while (choice != 3);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: In create account, why take `cin >> user.role` when you are already setting it above?

Comment: If you can't log in, verify that the members of `user` are what you're assuming them to be. (Spoiler: they're not.)

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this part of your code:

```
void createAccount() // function to create account
{
    User user;

    cout << "Select your role: " << endl;
    cout << "1. Tier I 2. Tier II 3. Tier III" << endl;

    int roleChoice; // variable for role selection
    cin >> roleChoice; // user selects role by inputing an integer

    switch (roleChoice) // switch enables 3 possible roles
    {
    case 1:
        user.role = "Tier I";
        break;
    case 2:
        user.role = "Tier II";
        break;
    case 3:
        user.role = "Tier III";
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Invalid role selected. Try again." << endl; // invalid input
        return;
    }

    cin >> user.role;
    cout << "Enter a user name: ";
    cin >> user.username;
    cout << "Enter a password: ";
    cin >> user.password;
    users.push_back(user); // push_back user adds a user to the vector User
    cout << "Account created successfully!\n";

}
```

You had already asked for the role choice and then you assigned based on the input the user does.

Then you put a  `cin >> user.role;` , which , as you guessed , asks the user the second time for the option.

And since (for example) you pressed 1 on the first try, the value of `user.role` would've been Tier I.

But since you pressed 1 again on the second try, the value of `user.role` would be 1. since you assigned 1 to it through second input. That was how you got the whole error on your program..

So all you need to do is remove that part of code.i.e remove  `cin >> user.role;` from the program , and it will work.

tell me if it works or not!!

Comment: wow I feel so dumb. You were correct, I did not notice that i was asking the user twice. These little errors are what drive me crazy in programming. Thank you very much, the program now works and only ask the user once.